# how to decode dart encoded readAsBytesSync() string in python

Tags: python, flutter, encoding

I am sending file type image to cloud server written in python. First of all, I am getting the content of file as list of bytes, then I am converting it to json to send to server.

```
List<int> imageBytes = img.readAsBytesSync();
var my_json = {"img":imageBytes};
var encoded = json.encode(my_json);
var channel =  IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://34.73.158.146:5903");
channel.sink.add(encoded);
```

So, please tell me how do readAsBytesSync() convert image to bytes, and how can I convert it back to image in python.
Also please tell me, what is the most appropriate way to encode and decode file type image in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter:

```
var params = {
      "image_file": base64Encode(_selectedImage.readAsBytesSync()),
    };

    final response = await http
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/upload_image_test/", body: params);
}
```

Python:

```
from PIL import Image, 
import io
import base64


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    received_data = request.data.get('image_file')
    decode_data = base64.b64decode(sent_data)

    byte_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decode_data))
    byte_image.show()
```

I tested it and it works. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer when you successfully test it.